# flv rtmp url for video-js

Tags: video, rtmp

I cannot get the code right in video-js player when wanting play rtmp url flv file. Does anyone know what it should be? I've tried following a number of examples at the blog reference site for video-js but nothing seems to work.

The Code I was trying to use is:

Oh the code won't input I don't know why sorry :(

Comment: Just checking, you do have a streaming server at the other end of the RTMP URL right?  Have you tested to make sure the stream itself works outside the video-js client?

Comment: Yes I do have a stream working outside of it. Trouble is I can't get any help with it because video-js developers want questions asked in stack overflow and I've been banned from asking any questions because they deem my questions to be too low grade. This is frustrating as am left out of online community to work out all myself.

Comment: But actually I have managed to get it to play since then but now having trouble with linking subtitles.

Comment: A configuration issue with video-js is probably off topic for StackOverflow anyway since it isn't particularly software development related.  If you don't mind my asking, what did the problem turn out to be?  You can feel free to answer your own question with your solution if you like.  You could also post the subtitles issue as another question since it really is a distinct question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link href="http://mysite.net/sites/all/libraries/video-js/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://mysite.net/sites/all/libraries/video-js/video.js"></script>
<script>
  videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://mysite.net/sites/all/libraries/video-js/video-js.swf"
</script>
<script src="http://mysite.net/sites/all/libraries/video-js/videosub.js"/></script>

<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
       controls=""
       data-setup="{&quot;example_option&quot;:true}"
       height="264"
       id="example_video_1"
       poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
       preload="auto"
       width="640">
  <source src="rtmp://mysite.net/oflaDemo/takeout.flv" type="rtmp/flv"/>
  <track kind="subtitle" label="English" src="http://mysite.net/takeout.srt" srclang="en-US" />
</video>
```

Comment: sorry having trouble getting the block of code inputed on here

Comment: the SRT is NOT working part of this answer but the flv is working.

Comment: What I think I need to use is a script called mediaelementsjs  and/or change permissions in xml for stream content